# '04 Daewoo Nubira brakes keep sticking on after disc and pad replacement

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, daewoo

On my '04 Daewoo Nubira I have been and had new discs and pads all round and now the brakes keep sticking on, I have been advised I now need new calipers all round, how can I tell if its them or that the ABS pump could be the problem as the garage will not say that this will fix my issue .

**I can't believe that all the calipers can go at the same time, is there anything I can do to fix this?**

Comment: Is Daewoo a subsidiary of Chevy? I'm trying to figure out why the chevrolet tag is on this.

Comment: Which wheels are sticking? if a valve in the abs unit fails it will be a diagonal pattern (this is pretty rare) i.e. left front, right rear. When one of the wheels stick, open the bleeder screw and try to spin the sticking wheel.

Comment: That's a good question.  If the shop didn't remove your brake pistons from the caliper and just pushed them back in to make room for the additional brake pad on the new pads, the brake pad dust and rotor/disc dust can jam up between the seal and the piston preventing the piston from retracting when you get off the brake.  This wouldn't be enough force to make the car slow, it merely drags the pads on the disc and makes a light grinding sounds as the disc turns across the pad surface that can't retract.

Comment: Hard to tell where the sticking is coming from without inspecting the car - it could be the caliper slide pins, which not all mechanics grease when reinstalling.

Perhaps take the car to a local quickfit-type place for a second opinion. I would be very hesitant to pay for new calipers all-round without knowing for sure that this is the problem; calipers don't break very often, so for four to go at once...

Comment: this sounds like old, worn brake pistons. On a different note, it `is` a daewoo, sell it asap and get a decent brand.

Answer (score 1):

1. First drive a bit and measure the temperature of the wheels with a
   gauge or even by touch. Whichever are hotter, that side is jamming.
2. Then based on that, remove the wheel, and remove the caliper.

Typical caliper consists of 2 pins that it moves on and one piston that pushes against the inner pad. The pins is what you are after. They should be easily movable in and out by hand.

If pins are ok, have a look at the piston and confirm that it's not rusted our and can move with some force if it's not a screw-in type.